# Any way to remove italic style from content inserted using :before class?

Tags: html, css

I have code like so

```
<li class="iconic camera">Pentax K-5 16 Megapixel DSLR</li>
```

I use CSS like

```
.iconic.camera:before {
font-size: 35px;
font-family: "KameraDings";
content: "A";
padding-right: 8px;
vertical-align: -10%;
}
```

to insert a Camera symbol with the special symbol font. However I have style for li's set to italic. Is there a way possible to remove italic from this one content letter ? I have tried `font-style: none;` to no avail

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's `font-style: normal;` not `font-style: none;`.

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/iqilor/2/edit)*

```
.iconic{
    font-style:italic;
}
  
.iconic.camera:before {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: "KameraDings";
    content: "A";
    padding-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: -10%;
    font-style:normal;            /* ta-da!*/
}
```